# Tableau: Using Date Slider Filter w/ NULL Cells

Tags: date, null, tableau-api

I have a sliding date range filter that is tied to a text table in Tableau. The text table shows addresses and lease expiration dates but some of the dates are blank and therefore show as NULL. When I use the sliding date range filter, the NULL data still shows. The picture below has the filter currently set to Jan 2020 - Sep 2040, yet the NULLs are still showing.

[image]

I do not want to completely remove the NULL data from the text table, only when the date filter is applied. In the edit Filter option, there is a button to 'Include Null Values'. If I unselect it, then the NULLs are removed from the text table.

[image]

How do I keep the NULLS in the text table and only remove them when the date slider is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem highlights a genuine need.  While, it seems to me, that there is no direct solution to your problem, still you can do one the few workarounds.

Consider the following sample data

[image]

**Workaround-1** create a new calculated field `NULL dates` with calculation as

```
ISNULL([DATE])
```

Now include this field (T/F) in the filter along with date range filter (with NULL values included indeed).  The two filters simultaneously can do your job

[image]

**Workaround-2** create a new date field wherein the null can either be shifted to just above or below the max/min of all the dates available.  Use this calculation-

```
IF ISNULL([Date]) = TRUE
then DATEADD('day', 1, {Max([Date])}) ELSE [Date] END
```

This will shift your null values to either end of the filter and whenever you'll filter that slider the dates will be filtered out else not.

[image]

Still I think first strategy with two filters should be better as it has more flexibility.